# ListView text is truncated -- how do I display the entire text of an item?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

Here's a picture of a System.Windows.Forms.ListView using LargeIcons

[image]

The selected item shows all it's text

e.g. The top left item shows only 11 characters of its name, it's shown fully if that's selected. How can I make it show all the text(or atleast more than 11 characters), for items that's not selected ?

Comment: You probably have to go owner drawn... This is standard behaviour, even in Windows Explorer.

Comment: When I set LargeIcon view in Explorer (win-7) this doesn't happen. the filenames, even *very* long ones, are always displayed fully.

Comment: Alternate idea: Have you tried using Tile view mode?

Answer (score 2):

There is DrawItem event http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.drawitem.aspx. Inside this event you have access to System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawString method.

```
void view_DrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Item.Text, drawFont, Brushes.Black, 
            new RectangleF(e.Item.Position.X,
                e.Item.Position.Y,
                20, 
                160));

    }
```

I entered some values for width/height, but you should use MeasureString or similar method.
Also do not forget to set OwnerDraw=true on ListView, otherwise it will not work.

Comment: This looks very promising, but what is "drawFont"? I get: "The name 'drawFont' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: OK, I created my own font based on the ListView's properties, but the result is 9X uglier than a bag of butts -- and I would have to add the icons in, too...there has to be a simpler way. It SHOULD be a property on ListView or ListViewItem ("ShowAllText" or some such).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem a while ago and solved by inserting a space after x characters and/or before a capital letter, so the text is wrapped where I wanted it to. This is somewhat a hack but it's an easy fix. You of course need to keep track of the changed you made to the text so you can reverse it if the user selects the item for further use.

Answer (score 0):

Caveat: this worked for me when the View type was **Details**, I haven't tried LargeIcons.

After writing output (mine was in bulk) to the listview add the following:

```
lstResults.AutoResizeColumn(0, ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize);
lstResults.AutoResizeColumn(1, ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent);
```